How to set up Keycloak SSO integration between two instances
I'm working on a project where we have multiple applications, each secured using Keycloak. Is there a way to establish SSO between two separate Keycloak instances.
I've researched a bit, but I'm unsure about the best approach for achieving this. Would it involve configuring Keycloak instances in a specific way or implementing custom code? Any guidance, documentation references, or examples would be greatly appreciated.
